# Passing a method as a parameter in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parameters, methods

I am trying to learn Ruby, and want to implement the Python algorithms from the book "Programming Collective Intelligence" in Ruby.

In chapter 8 the author passed a method as a parameter which seems to work in Python but not in Ruby.

I am using the method:

```
def gaussian(dist, sigma=10.0)
  foo
end
```

and want to call this using another method:

```
def weightedknn(data, vec1, k = 5, weightf = gaussian)
  foo
  weight = weightf(dist)
  foo
end
```

But I got is an error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You want a proc object:

```
gaussian = Proc.new do |dist, *args|
  sigma = args.first || 10.0
  ...
end

def weightedknn(data, vec1, k = 5, weightf = gaussian)
  ...
  weight = weightf.call(dist)
  ...
end
```

Just note that you can't set a default argument in a block declaration like that.  So you need to use a splat and setup the default in the proc code itself.

---

Or, depending on your scope of all this, it may be easier to pass in a method name instead.

```
def weightedknn(data, vec1, k = 5, weightf = :gaussian)
  ...
  weight = self.send(weightf)
  ...
end
```

In this case you are just calling a method that is defined on an object rather than passing in a complete chunk of code.  Depending on how you structure this you may need replace `self.send` with `object_that_has_the_these_math_methods.send`

---

Last but not least, you can hang a block off the method.

```
def weightedknn(data, vec1, k = 5)
  ...
  weight = 
    if block_given?
      yield(dist)
    else
      gaussian.call(dist)
    end
  end
  ...
end

weightedknn(foo, bar) do |dist|
  # square the dist
  dist * dist
end
```

But it sounds like you would like more reusable chunks of code here.

Comment: I think that second option is the best option (that is, using Object.send()), the drawback is that you need to use a class for all of it (which is how you should do in OO anyway :)). It is more DRY than passing a block (Proc) all the time, and you could even pass arguments trough the wrapper method.

Comment: As an addition, if you want to do `foo.bar(a,b)` with send, it is `foo.send(:bar, a, b)`. The splat (*) operator allows you to do `foo.send(:bar, *[a,b])` should you find you want to have an arbitrary lengthed array of arguments - assuming the bar method can soak them up

Answer (score 117):

The comments referring to blocks and Procs are correct in that they are more usual in Ruby. But you can pass a method if you want. You call `method` to get the method and `.call` to call it:

```
def weightedknn( data, vec1, k = 5, weightf = method(:gaussian) )
  ...
  weight = weightf.call( dist )
  ...
end
```

Comment: This is interesting. It's worth noting that you call `method( :<name> )` just once when converting your method name to a callable symbol. You can store that result in a variable or a parameter and keep passing it to child functions like any other variable from then on...

Comment: Or maybe, instead of using the _method_ syntax in the argument list, you can use it while invoking the method as follows :

weightedknn( data, vec1, k, method( :gaussian) )

Comment: This method is better than mucking around with a proc or block, since you don't have to handle parameters - it just works with whatever the method wants.

Comment: For completion, if you want to pass a method defined somewhere else, do `SomewhereElse.method(:method_name)`. That's pretty cool!

Comment: This may be its own question but, how can I determine if a symbol references a function or something else? I tried `:func.class` but that's just a `symbol`

Comment: awesome @medik. Love it. Or you just pass the object

Answer (score 58):

You can pass a method as parameter with `method(:function)` way. Below is a very simple example:

```
def double(a)
  return a * 2 
end
=> nil

def method_with_function_as_param( callback, number) 
  callback.call(number) 
end 
=> nil

method_with_function_as_param( method(:double) , 10 ) 
=> 20
```

Comment: I faced an issue for a method with a more complicated scope, and finally figured out how to do, hope this can help someone :
If your method is for example in another class, you should call the last line of code like `method_with_function_as_param(Class.method(:method_name),...)` and not `method(:Class.method_name)`

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I discovered the method called `method`. Made my day but I guess that's why I prefer functional languages, no need to make such acrobatics to get what you want. Anyway, I dig ruby

Answer (score 26):

The normal Ruby way to do this is to use a block.

So it would be something like:

```
def weightedknn(data, vec1, k = 5)
  foo
  weight = yield(dist)
  foo
end
```

And used like:

```
weightedknn(data, vec1) { |dist| gaussian( dist ) }
```

This pattern is used extensively in Ruby.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `&` operator on the `Method` instance of your method to *convert the method to a block*.

Example:

```
def foo(arg)
  p arg
end

def bar(&block)
  p 'bar'
  block.call('foo')
end

bar(&method(:foo))
```

More details at http://weblog.raganwald.com/2008/06/what-does-do-when-used-as-unary.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the method "call" of the function object:

```
weight = weightf.call( dist )
```

EDIT: as explained in the comments, this approach is wrong. It would work if you're using Procs instead of normal functions.

Comment: When he does `weightf = gaussian` in the arg list it's actually trying to execute `gaussian` and assign the result as the default value of weightf.  The call doesn't have required args and crashes.  So weightf is not even a proc object with a call method just yet.

Comment: This (ie. doing it wrong and the comment explaining why) actually allowed me to fully understand the accepted answer, so thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use ampersand to have an access to named blocks within a function. Following the recommendations given in [this article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2006/04/18/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-methods/) you can write something like this (this is a real scrap from my working program):

```
  # Returns a valid hash for html form select element, combined of all entities
  # for the given +model+, where only id and name attributes are taken as
  # values and keys correspondingly. Provide block returning boolean if you
  # need to select only specific entities.
  #
  # * *Args*    :
  #   - +model+ -> ORM interface for specific entities'
  #   - +&cond+ -> block {|x| boolean}, filtering entities upon iterations
  # * *Returns* :
  #   - hash of {entity.id => entity.name}
  #
  def make_select_list( model, &cond )
    cond ||= proc { true } # cond defaults to proc { true }
    # Entities filtered by cond, followed by filtration by (id, name)
    model.all.map do |x|
      cond.( x ) ? { x.id => x.name } : {}
    end.reduce Hash.new do |memo, e| memo.merge( e ) end
  end
```

Afterwerds, you can call this function like this:

```
@contests = make_select_list Contest do |contest|
  logged_admin? or contest.organizer == @current_user
end
```

If you don't need to filter your selection, you simply omit the block:

```
@categories = make_select_list( Category ) # selects all categories
```

So much for the power of Ruby blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to a [Proc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522771/9527665) or a [method call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523996/9527665), you can also pass a lambda as `weightf` parameter :

```
def main
  gaussian = -> (params) {
    ...
  }
  weightedknn(data, vec1, k = 5, gaussian, params)
  # Use symbol :gaussian if method exists instead
end
```

```
def weightedknn(data, vec1, k = 5, weightf, params)
  ...
  weight = weightf.call(params)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score -8):

you also can use "eval", and pass the method as a string argument, and then simply eval it in the other method.

Comment: This is really bad practice, never do it!

Comment: @Developer why is this considered bad practice?

Comment: Among performance reasons, the `eval` can execute arbitrary code so it is extremely vulnerable to various attacks.