# Pass a function by name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

How can you pass a function by name in Ruby? (I've only been using Ruby for a few hours, so I'm still figuring things out.)

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# This works, but is more verbose than I'd like    
nums.each do |i|
  puts i
end

# In JS, I could just do something like:
# nums.forEach(console.log)

# In F#, it would be something like:
# List.iter nums (printf "%A")

# In Ruby, I wish I could do something like:
nums.each puts
```

Can it be done similarly concisely in Ruby? Can I just reference the function by name instead of using a block?

**People voting to close:** Can you explain why this isn't a real question?

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522720/passing-a-method-as-a-parameter-in-ruby

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
nums.each(&method(:puts))
```

[This article](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) has a good explanation of the differences between procs, blocks, and lambdas in Ruby.

Comment: It's also possible to specify an instance method, e.g. `nums.each(&$stderr.method(:puts))`

Answer (score 3):

*Can I just reference the function by name instead of wrapping it in a block?*

You aren't 'wrapping' it -- the block *is* the function.

If brevity is a concern, you can use brackets instead of `do..end`:

```
nums.each {|i| puts i}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not out-of-the-box, although you can use `method`:

```
def invoke(enum, meth)
  enum.each { |e| method(meth).call(e) }
end
```

I prefer it wrapped up into a monkeypatched `Enumerable`.

There are other ways to go about this, too; this is kind of brute-force.