# Ruby - Passing functions as arguments

Tags: ruby

I want to pass two functions as methods like so:

```
def add_user_review(user_id, movie_id, set=:training)
  check_set set, @training_data.add_user_review(user_id, movie_id), @test_data.add_user_review(user_id, movie_id)
end
```

where the `check_set` method looks like:

```
# If set is training set, initiate training set function. else, initiate test set function
def check_set(set, training_method, test_method)
  set == :training ? training_method : test_method
end
```

I have methods that behave one of two ways depending on `set` (either `:training` or `:test`). Both `@training_data` and `@test_data` are objects from another class, and `training_method` will always be called on `@training_data`, likewise for `test_method` and `@test_data`. Each method accepts different parameters (i.e. not all are passing `user_id` and `movie_id`).

I need to refactor my code to incorporate a Proc or something. What should I do?

Comment: this might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522720/passing-a-method-as-a-parameter-in-ruby

Comment: Speaking of stack overflow, isn't that what results when you invoke `add_user_review`?

Comment: Your `check_set` can be refactored to `def check_set(_, training_method, _); training_method end`.

Comment: The error that results when I invoke `add_user_review` is undefined method `add_user_review` for nil::NilClass. And this is happening because `@test_data` does not exist. The method is executing both methods before passing the results to `check_set`, when what I want is for `check_set` to decide which method should be called.

Comment: Is `check_set` called from other places?

Comment: @JoelL, I had seen that question earlier, but I'm not sure how it helps me: I don't want to call a block of code, I want to call a method defined in a separate object (`@training_data` refers to an object I defined).

Comment: @lurker, yes, `check_set` is called in several methods that all had this same behavior: if set is of a certain type, execute one method, else execute this other method. That's why I'm trying to create this one method that all can refer to.

Comment: Here is your answer using `Proc`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522720/passing-a-method-as-a-parameter-in-ruby

Comment: @MagedMakled, that post's information is what I was trying to use, but it was not working correctly. See the answer I marked below for an implementation that is working.

Comment: @eugene1832, I meant to use a `Proc` in general. did you get it or you still need help?

Comment: @MagedMakled, ah I see, in that case yes, that is what I went for. I did get it! Thanks to the response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation with procs. The proc only gets executed when you do `call` on it.

```
 def add_user_review(user_id, movie_id, set=:training)
    check_set set, proc { @training_data.add_user_review(user_id, movie_id) }, proc { @test_data.add_user_review(user_id, movie_id) }
  end

 def check_set(set, training_method, test_method)
   set == :training ? training_method.call() : test_method.call()
 end
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do this by calling `Proc.new( { <method> } ), which was failing. Thank you for showing me the correct syntax.